# min value required to process all values

Tags: java, math

There are two persons`(A, B)` and they exchanges money with each other.

For example,

```
values to be exchanged {50,50,50,50}
value from whom to whom {ABAB}
```

In `from whom to whom`, at every char index shows that person who is on receiving end to get money. Like at `index 0`, `A` will be getting money from `B`. Amount value at every exchange will be the at the same index in `values to be exchanged` as character index in `from whom to whom`

I want to know, min initial money required for each A and B to complete this whole exchange (`values to be exchanged & value from whom to whom` )

This is the code, I'm just trying to understand the math over here, How negated min value is becoming the min balances required to complete the whole exchange ? Code I can understand but not the math behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation starts with zero values. During exchanges persons' balances reach negative values.

To make **real** exchanges, you have to **add absolute value of minimal** negative balances, so balances never will negative.

Imagine graph of balance for a person. It is saw-like polyline, and you have to lift it up until the most bottom teeth becomes 0.

(add value 3 for this graph)

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to understand, if negative values which are added to min initial balances, then we might leaving values/exchanges which are done before reaching negative values, then how come only considering negative value as initial min balance will complete the all exchanges mentioned in array ? bit confused here

Comment: We don't know ahead, what balance should be enough, so take arbitrary 0. After calculations we can see what the most negative value was (**-3** at the graph), so we can add **3 (positive value!)** to provide non-negative balance elsewhere.

Comment: is it correct, if lets say some initial exchanges went fine but after that balance reaches to negative, so exchanges went fine <<plus>> negate of negative value will be the min required initial balance to complete all exchanges...right ?

Comment: Emm.. If I understand  correctly - We temporarily allow to make negative balance to find minimum one. Then make correction, after correction all balances will be positive. Yes, this is right.

Comment: You can also consider another edge solution - assign obviously large initial balance (say sum of all exchanges). After the loop subtract minimal reached value to provide minimal possible balance. Note that subtraction of minimum is the same as "minus minimum"

Comment: can you please share any pseudo code of your logic you mentioned in your last comment ?

Comment: All changes:   `int balA = 9000; ... System.out.println(9000-minA);` I just wanted to show that (-minA) is (0-minA)

Comment: one thing I'm unable to understand, if this is {50,50,30,50} exchange and whose total sum is 180, but answer is A=30, B=50(which is only 80 in total) initial balance required to complete all exchanges because minus 30 and minus 50 was coming as negative values for A and B respectively. I'm struggling to understand this math that, how come only negative values are able to cover all exchanges including the +ve ones (obvious ones) and negative ones too ?

Comment: Do you understand graph in my answer?

Comment: 50-50,not full..can you help more to understand ?

Comment: balance of person reaches some values below initial balance, bit difference usually is not sum of all values, because money are moving back and forth. Only if all transactions are from one person to another like {AAAAA} then difference reaches overall sum

Comment: really appreciate your effort, but I'm still struggling to understand <<bit difference usually is not sum of all values, because money are moving back and forth> :(

Comment: Look at the graph. transactions are 2,3,4,5,1,4,2,1. Sum is 22 but min negative is -3 because signs of transactions do change (-+-++--++)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254420/discussion-between-oxana-grey-and-mbo).

Comment: I run out of power...